# Missing module when installing Sublime Text 3 on Debian

Tags: python, debian, installation, sublimetext3

I downloaded the Sublime Text 3 archive from the official page for 32bit Debian. I extracted it and I ran the file `PackageSetup.py` with `Python2.7`. It gave me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sublime_plugin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sublime
ImportError: No module named sublime
```

There is indeed no file named "sublime" in that archive, so what do I do now?

Comment: Why did you extract the `.deb` file? The scripts contained within are meant to be run in a certain way, at a certain time, by certain programs, with certain arguments. Of course you're going to get errors if you just try to run something yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian packages come in `.deb` format. You just need to double-click it or run `sudo dpkg -i /full/path/to/file.deb`.

No need to extract it and run the scripts by hand.

This may help you: http://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-install-sublime-text-3-on-debian/